# Copy code in batch file to subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I have just heard that we can copy the file to all its subfolders using a batch file.

I have a file named `code.php` and many folders in **project** folder.

Now instead of copy-paste `code.php` in all its(project) sub folders one by one. Is there any code in the batch file that will do the same, by opening batch file once.

Comment: Recursively or just in the folders in the first level?

Comment: I am not able to understand your comment. Basically, I want it to be copied in **project/1**, **project/2**, **project/3**, **project/3/1** & so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this should do what you want.

At the Command Prompt:

```bat
For /D /R "C:\project" %A In (*) Do @Copy "C:\code.php" "%A">Nul
```

or in a batch file:

```bat
@For /D /R "C:\project" %%A In (*) Do @Copy "C:\code.php" "%%A">Nul
```

Change the parent root folder path `C:\project` and source file name and path `C:\code.php` accordingly.

Comment: If I add `batch file` in **project** folder then also I have to write `C:\project`?

Comment: If the batch file is in your `project` directory you could miss out `"C:\project"`, `@For /D /R %%A In (*) Do @Copy "C:\code.php" "%%A">Nul`. If `code.php` was also in the `project` directory you could potentially use, `@For /D /R %%A In (*) Do @Copy code.php "%%A">Nul`.

Comment: Any link to learn `.bat` files? As for learning `HTML` is **w3school**